# Image not showing(Blank space) while using glide library in android

Tags: java, android, android-glide

Image is showing nothing not even the image I chose as default no error nothing just the image cannot be loaded I granted internet permission still this is happening plz help
No error is there in logcat.
App launches everything is fine but the image wont load i tried waiting still and the API is working fine......i dunno if its my code or the permission which is causing this...

**Java Code**

```
package com.example.meme_share;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView i = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }

    public void loadmeme() {
        RequestQueue a = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
        JsonObjectRequest b = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                String u = null;
                try {
                    u = response.getString("url");
                    System.out.println("Raunak"+u);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Raunak"+u);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(u).into(i);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:text="Next"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.93"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="415dp"
        android:layout_height="538dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.06"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="182dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="134dp"
        android:text="Share"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.956" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.meme_share">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Meme_Share">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: share the error code

Comment: there is no error

Answer (score 1):

You have created two `ImageView i;` variables: first in `onCreate` methon and second in class scope.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        i = findViewById(R.id.imageView); // < here
    }
```

Besides this problem here are some others:

2. You don't call loadmeme method anywhere
3. You don't make network request

```
    ImageView imageView; // 1. Use class scoped imageView

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        // 2. Run loadmeme method
        loadmeme();
    }

    public void loadmeme() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme";
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                String u = null;
                try {
                    u = response.getString("url");
                    System.out.println("Raunak" + u);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("Raunak" + u);
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(u).into(imageView);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error occurred", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        // 3. Add request to queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Nthing is happening after declaring it one time on class scope and assigning in oncreate method prblm still remains the same

Comment: @Raunak_Shalya i have updated the answer, but you should using better naming for variables and reading documentation of library that you are using.

Comment: @Raunak_Shalya if my help was useful for you, can you mark this as answer?